Выкачивание большого кол-ва данных из DropBox в Excel
У меня есть Dropbox c 61940 картинками, на каждую из этих картинок мне надо создать и скопировать ссылку, полное название файла(картинки) и ссылку(получается текущий url) на раздел в котором находится эта ссылка. Главный вопрос - как это реализовать? Может есть API который предоставляет все эти функции? Может есть наброски кода(примеры хотя бы)? Из входных данных - картинки, ссылки на раздел в которых находятся эти картинки, количество разделов, количество картинок в одном разделе(326), количество всех картинок.

Скорее всего, разделы названы однотипно. Поэтому копируете ссылку на один раздел и в Excel генерируете ссылки на остальные разделы (в Excel есть отличные возможности для такой работы).
Если картинки названы однотипно, то такой же подход. Если нет, то тогда через API.
